# Configuration file for mpicc

Tags: mpi, config, mpich

I'm looking for the rules and a simple example on how to write a configuration file for `mpicc` and `mpifort` for MPICH that can be specified at compilation time with `mpicc -config=name`. My goal is to be able to run MPI applications using the same MPICH installation and different compilers and runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the MPICH man pages you can consult the man page for mpicc, which documents several ways you can select different compilers.

The syntax for these config files is not well documented (which is no doubt why you are here).  The config files should contain bash-style variable assignments. e. g. CC=gcc or CC=icc

What would you wish to set in such a config file?  Probably this list suffices:

- CC                 - C compiler
- WRAPPER_CFLAGS        - Any special flags needed to compile
- WRAPPER_LDFLAGS       - Any special flags needed to link
- WRAPPER_LIBS          - Any special libraries needed in order to link